# PsSuspendProcess blocking / waiting / stuck - Windows Kernel Programming

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver, minifilter

i come here with a very low level question in the Windows Kernel.
I am in a callback function on a minifilter driver.
The goal of the driver is to pause any process witch try to open a file I marked as protected.
I'm using PsSuspendProcess that I got from this function :

```
(pPsSuspendProcess)ReturnSystemRoutineAddress(L"PsSuspendProcess");
```

But when I call it with the above code, my program get stuck at the Suspend call.
On the task manager, the process is well suspended, but the driver never ends this function.

It only continues when I unpause manually the process or kill it from taskmgr.

I'm totally blocked, as PsSuspendProcess is an undocumented function...

Here my code:

```
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS
DfPreCreateCallback(
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _Outptr_result_maybenull_ PVOID* CompletionContext
    )
{
    PAGED_CODE();
    NTSTATUS status;
    ULONG options = Data->Iopb->Parameters.Create.Options;
    UCHAR disposition = (options >> 24) & 0xff;
    ULONG createOptions = (options << 8) >> 8;

    if ((createOptions & FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE) && (disposition == FILE_OPEN || disposition == FILE_OPEN_IF
        || disposition == FILE_OVERWRITE || disposition == FILE_OVERWRITE_IF))
    {
        HANDLE processId = (HANDLE)FltGetRequestorProcessId(Data);
        PEPROCESS p = FltGetRequestorProcess(Data);
        if (p == NULL)
            goto callback_end;
        LPSTR processName = PsGetProcessImageFileName(p);
        if (processName == NULL)
            goto callback_end;
        for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(ExcludedProcess) / sizeof(LPCWSTR)); i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(processName, ExcludedProcess[i]) == 0)
                goto callback_end;
        }

        PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION FileInfo;
        status = FltGetFileNameInformation(Data, FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED | FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_ALWAYS_ALLOW_CACHE_LOOKUP, &FileInfo);
        if (NT_ERROR(status))
            goto callback_end;
        if (!IsProtected(&FileInfo->Name))
            goto callback_end;
        DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "DBG PROTECTED %wZ", FileInfo->Name);

        PsSuspendProcess(p);

        DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "DBG SUSPENDED")
    }
    callback_end:
    CompletionContext = NULL;
    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
}
```

Comment: *my program get stuck* - what is **your** program ? you suspend **current** process and **current** thread as well. of course `DbgPrintEx` with "DBG SUSPENDED" will be not executed.

Comment: "My program" is the minifilter driver
I suspend the process witch are opening my file, not the current driver process.

aswell, in LPSTR processName, I can find "notepad.exe" for example

Comment: look like you still not understand. *not the current driver process* - ?! what is *driver process* ?! you suspend current thread. so what you want ?

Comment: I used PsSuspendProcess with parameter "p". "p" is defined by FltGetRequestorProcess(Data), witch gives me a pointer to the EPROCESS of the process who opened my protected file.
How can this call suspend my current driver thread ? And if it does, why the process pointed by the PEPROCESS gets paused ?

It you think I'm totally wrong, please tell me what I should do to suspend the process that is opening my protected file.

Comment: *current driver thread* ?!?

Comment: you suspend current thread. and this is all. you need study in which context executed kernel code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you call by fact

```
PsSuspendProcess(FltGetRequestorProcess(Data));
```

but for file operations Pre Callbacks almost always called in context of thread that requested a given I/O operation. so almost always

```
FltGetRequestorProcess(Data) == IoGetCurrentProcess();
```

so you suspend **current** process and **current** thread. as result next line

```
DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "DBG SUSPENDED");
```

of course will be not executed until thread will be not resumed

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, i understood. I thinked it was like the PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine.

Comment: @Tom - no, top level drivers almost allways called in context of I/O requestor process.

Comment: @Tom - in all case suspend process have no sense. what you will be do next with this process ? when you resume it ? it you not plan resume - better just terminate process. for this you need queue work item, from it call `ZwTerminateProcess` and than `KeSetEvent` and in pre callback wait on this event.. but really what you need - return `FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE` and block open file

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to block a pre-I/O operation and suspend the process requesting that operation using `FltQueueDeferredIoWorkItem`

```
                            PFLT_DEFERRED_IO_WORKITEM workItem = NULL;

                            workItem = FltAllocateDeferredIoWorkItem();

                            if (workItem != NULL) {

                                if (Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_WRITE) {
                                    status = FltLockUserBuffer(Data);
                                }
                                else {
                                    status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
                                }

                                if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {

                                    status = FltQueueDeferredIoWorkItem(workItem, Data, FilterWorkerCallback, DelayedWorkQueue, CompletionContext);

                                    if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
                                        return FLT_PREOP_PENDING;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        KdPrint(("FilterPreIoOp -> FltQueueDeferredIoWorkItem routine failed (Error: 0x%X).\r\n", status));
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    KdPrint(("FilterPreIoOp -> FltLockUserBuffer routine failed (Error: 0x%X).\r\n", status));
                                }

                            }
                            else {
                                KdPrint(("FilterPreIoOp -> Unable to allocate memory for the worker item.\r\n"));
                            }
```

The worker routine

```
VOID FLTAPI FilterWorkerCallback(_In_ PFLT_DEFERRED_IO_WORKITEM FltWorkItem, _In_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA CallbackData, _In_opt_ PVOID Context) {

    // Do some deferred I/O work here

    NTSTATUS status;

    PEPROCESS prcs = FltGetRequestorProcess(CallbackData);
    ULONG prcsId = FltGetRequestorProcessId(CallbackData);

    status = PsSuspendProcess(prcs);

    if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        KdPrint(("FilterWorkerCallback -> Process with PID %lu suspended successfully.\r\n", prcsId));
    }
    else {
        KdPrint(("FilterWorkerCallback -> Unable to suspend process %lu \r\n", prcsId));
    }

    FltCompletePendedPreOperation(CallbackData, FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE, NULL);

    // Free the work item
    FltFreeDeferredIoWorkItem(FltWorkItem);

}
```